# Find reduction from Hamiltonian Cycle to Double Hamiltonian Cycle

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, hamiltonian-circuit

$$DoubleHC=\{G\,| \text{G has at least two Hamiltonian Cycles}\}$$
I think about take a graph with HC and add to it two vertexes and edges to two randomally vertexes, but without success. Is my try good? or I have to go in other way? 
Also full solution is good.

Comment: What specifically didn't work out?